# Reworking Lvl-Up - gain skill points to spend

Tags: rubygame, rpgmakermv

Alright, so in rpg maker vx ace I am trying to get lvl-ups to work in this way;

every third Lvl-Up you will gain a skill point, which you can spend on a skill that you are interested in.

I'm new to this (currently in my second week) and have essentially no knowledge on how to do this, so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Currently I am (attempting to be) using a script that I found online, but there are issues with line 139; TypeError; cant convert String into Integer.... (line 50 in the Pastebin; https://pastebin.com/sKRrraPZ )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.